# PIL get image pixels returns black color for a transparent image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

```
img = img.convert('RGBA')
r, g, b, a = img.getpixel((0, 0))
```

For an image with a transparent background, why does this code see the leftmost pixel as black (0, 0, 0, 0)?
I absolutely need to see him as a transparent being, not black.

Comment: The last value of the tuple stands for alpha, which is 0, and as such transparent. What would you want the RGB values to be for it to count as transparent?